# How to generate 'minitest/spec' based gems via bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, minitest, gem-bundler

```
bundle gem gem_name --test=minitest
```

allows for choosing minitest, but how to make bundler generate code for minitest/spec instead of minitest/test.

Comment: feature was turned down back in 2016  https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/5150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible.

> ```
>  -t, --test=minitest, --test=rspec
> ```
>
> Specify the test framework that Bundler should use when generating
>   the  project.  Acceptable     values  are  minitest  and  rspec.  The 
>   GEM_NAME.gemspec  will be configured and a skeleton   test/spec
>   directory will be created based on this option. If this option is
>   unspecified,  an  interactive prompt will be displayed and the answer
>   will be saved in Bundler's global config  for future bundle gem use.

However the `bundle gem` generator generates less than 10 lines of tests, so converting to `MiniTest::Spec` is hardly a herculean task.

Comment: I wonder why they prefer rspec over minitest/spec! as minitest/spec is packaged with ruby itself

Comment: RSpec has been around much longer and is more popular. Oh yeah and the docs dont suck.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work now:

`bundle gem myapp --test minitest`